# Where can I get the Final Fantasy XIV client?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I'd like to give Final Fantasy XIV another shot.  I purchased the game when it first came out, but I don't have the install disk anymore.  Where can I download the client?  Googling, and searching the FF XIV forums turn up nothing.

Comment: You might want to wait until *A Realm Reborn* is released. Surely, Square Enix will let owners of the original play the rerelease?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Final Fantasy XIV is currently offline; the original version of the game was shut down in late 2012 to prepare for the upcoming remake/update, *Final Fantasy XIV: A Realm Reborn*,  which will be released on August 27, 2013. *A Realm Reborn* will be available as a free upgrade for anyone who purchased the original game.

Since you're already an owner of the original game, you will be able to play *A Realm Reborn* as long as you have either registered your original FFXIV registration key to your Square-Enix account, or you still have the original registration key in your possession. In the latter case, it will still be possible to register your original key to your account once *ARR* has been released.

Furthermore, if you already own the Collector's Edition of FFXIV, you'll receive the [digital items included in the ARR Collector's Edition](http://na.finalfantasyxiv.com/product/index.html) for no charge.

From Square-Enix's Lodestone post [here](http://lodestone.finalfantasyxiv.com/pl/topics/detail?id=14019fb32d90859f118dccb8cd96bf81c212957d):

> **Players Who Own FFXIV Version 1.0**
>
> Players who own FFXIV version 1.0
>   will not need to purchase the PC version of FFXIV: ARR and will be
>   able to download the FFXIV: ARR software for free.
>
> - Details on downloading the FFXIV: ARR software will be provided at a later date.
>
> Furthermore, users who have version 1.0 registration codes that have
>   not yet been registered will be able to register them and play FFXIV:
>   ARR on PC at the start of the service.

In the meantime, [you can still sign up for the ARR beta](https://secure.square-enix.com/enqt/e/FF14RBETAENTRYN/html?) if you'd like.